# How to define "externalIP" range during Openshift cluster installation?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I'm looking the way to define **externalIP** range during Openshift cluster installation ( via declarations in install-config.yaml ).

Openshift docs for 4.3 and later version ( [linky](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.3/installing/installing_bare_metal/installing-bare-metal.html#installation-bare-metal-config-yaml_installing-bare-metal) ) did not provide any fields for that.

Older definition ( externalIPNetworkCIDR ) from 3.5 ( [linky](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/admin_guide/tcp_ingress_external_ports.html#service-externalip) ) doesn't seems to work ether.

Comment: Using bare-metal, as of v4, you should be able to create Services with an `externalIPs: [ 1.2.3.4 ]`, without having to provision a range - result may vary depending on SDN, didn't check openvswitch in a while. Make sure that your underlying network does route those IPs to your OpenShift nodes, SDN would take it on from there.

Comment: Thank you, I had to be more clear - I'm looking to achieve AutoAssignement behavior.

Comment: I don't think this is possible in OpenShift as of v4. Unless using cloud integration and LoadBalancer services, externalIPs would now have to be explicitly set. As an alternative, I've seen an OCP customer write their own "LoadBalancer Services" operator, on bare-metal, allocating IPs to their LoadBalancer Services, querying some third-party IPAM. RH's been re-inventing openshift, with that v4. Some features were lost, others are not as stable as they used to in v3, ... Sticking with kubernetes native stuff is usually better, if you don't want to lose support eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually you can:

first create the openshift install manifests

```
./openshift-install create manifests --dir=<installation_directory>
```

check the output:

```
ls <installation_directory>/manifests/cluster-network-*

cluster-network-01-crd.yml
cluster-network-02-config.yml
cluster-network-03-config.yml
```

edit this file cluster-network-03-config.yml:

```
apiVersion: operator.openshift.io/v1
kind: Network
metadata:
  name: cluster
spec: 
  clusterNetwork:
  - cidr: 10.128.0.0/14
    hostPrefix: 23
  externalIP:
    autoAssignCIDRs:
      - 10.0.0.0/16
    policy:
      allowedCIDRs:
        - 10.0.0.0/16
  serviceNetwork:
  - 172.30.0.0/16
  defaultNetwork:
    type: OpenShiftSDN
    openshiftSDNConfig:
      mode: NetworkPolicy
      mtu: 1450
      vxlanPort: 4789
```

proceed with the install route:

```
./openshift-install create ignition-configs --dir=<installation_directory>
```

maybe to note that this is the way you can configure basically everything at cluster install :)

in install-config.yaml directly its not possible, i rised a github issue a few months ago but it gained no views:
https://github.com/openshift/installer/issues/4275

most of the knowledge coming from here:
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/installing/installing_bare_metal/installing-bare-metal-network-customizations.html

Answer (score 0):

As per RH "we can't specify externalIP parameter during the cluster installation, it should be done post-installation."